# Function for all the ids that starting with "abc_google_" or "abc_facebook_"

Tags: jquery

I want to make a click function for all the ids that starting with:

```
abc_google_
abc_facebook_
abc_cnn_
```

how can I do it in one line?

```
$('[id^="abc_google_"]').live("click", function () {
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: _Just_ these three?  Or are there others? Any other starting with `abc` that you don't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple selectors with `,` just like in CSS:

```
$('[id^="abc_google_"],[id^="abc_facebook_"],[id^="abc_cnn_"]').click(...)
```

Alternatively, delegate the handler to the body and check if the target (or any parent thereof) has an ID that matches.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('div[id^="abc_"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

When each id have abc_ prefix why don't try :

```
$("[id^='abc_']")live("click", function () {
       var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
       alert('ID => '+ id); //for test
});
```

or use , to seprate ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        $('*').click(function(this) {
        if(this.id).contains('abc_'){    
            // you code here.... 
        }
    });
```